# How should we use @android:style/Theme.Material.Light on Lollipop and above ? Where and how should we use it?

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat, android-theme, android-compatibility

Created basic project inAndroid Studio with minSdkVersion 21 and targetSdkVersion 25. In default project has Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar.
I wanted to understand if I can apply @android:style/Theme.Material.Light to my style but ap crashed while inflating the view with error : "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.". So I changed AppCompatActivity to Activity hoping it should work. Got Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.

Is applying @android:style/Theme.Material.Light from Lollipop with base Activity and above not same as applying Theme.AppCompat with AppCompatActivity **??** If not same, what I am gonna miss from @android:style/Theme.Material.Light if I use compat. **??**

I understood from other posts and android docs that we have to use activity and themse from AppCompat. Is this the only way **??**

I tried to see if the parent styles are same..but they finally inherit different styles from ../sdk/platforms/android-25/data/res/values/themes_material.xml.

Throw some light on how they work and where to use what.

Comment: TL,DR: Use AppCompat even if your minSdkVersion is 21. Support libraries fix various platform bugs and bring you features from new Android versions. That and Design library needs AppCompat.

Comment: Okay @EugenPechanec. Thanks for information. Is the Material Theme is not for devs to use but just part of the framework ? Can I override all properties of Material theme in my Appcompat theme ?

Comment: Any theme the IDE offers you is part of public API and available to devs. AppCompat is an overlay that makes backwards compatibility easier. AppCompat has many theme attributes mirroring those of AOSP (e.g. `buttonStyle` instead of `android:buttonStyle`), override these. Some such as `android:textColorPrimary` remain.